# Advanced Custom Fields Conditional Statement on Tag Page

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I have Advanced Custom Fields installed and have added a custom field on the edit tag page, it is an for an image to show for different tags. I'm trying to create a conditional statement to work like this in archive.php:

if tag image
show image
else
show something else

The code i'm using just doesnt show anything and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, could somebody help please.

```
<?php
global $post;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$tag_image = get_field('tag_image',$post->ID);
if($tag_image['url'] != '')
{ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $tag_image['url']; ?>" />
<?php echo tag_description(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo tag_description(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use $tag_image['url'] inorder to get image source

```
$tag_image = get_field('tag_image',$post->ID);          

if($tag_image['url'] != '')
{ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $tag_image['url']; ?>"/>
<?php
}else{
  Do some thing
 }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: No, the conditional statement still doesnt work, thanks. I dont think echoing the fields is the problem

Comment: Hi Manohar, thanks but no that still doesnt work. Does this need to be in a loop?

Comment: Yes it needs to be in a loop so that ID's will be passed automatically , with out ID you cant access the custom field

Comment: No that doesnt work either now, the whole area goes blank and doesnt even show the tag description

Answer (score 0):

Is `tag_image` the path to the image? Try a simple `<?php echo ('tag_image')?>` to make sure the data is there...?

Answer (score 0):

I think Your loop not getting ID's properly Try the below code

```
global $post;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$tag_image = get_field('tag_image',$post->ID);
if($tag_image['url'] != '')
{                   
echo $tag_image['url'];
}
endwhile;
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Hi Manohar, I tried and it was just blank space again. I have edited my top code to exactly what im using now. Is there anything wrong with that, not from what i can see?